# How do I disable the swipe to unlock curtain?

Tags: gnome, suspend, gdm

My computer is not a phone. This swipe to unlock thing is ridiculous.  Yes, I know <kbd>Esc</kbd> is supposed to substitute for the swipe, but the whole curtain thing does not interact well with my video setup.  I want to disable the curtain completely.  When I wake my computer from sleep, I want to instantly see the desktop.

How do I do this?

Some stuff about my setup:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

```
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4
```

---

```
$ gdm3 --version
GDM 3.28.2
```

---

```
$ ps auwwwx | grep session | cut -c65-
 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-launch-environment]
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session gnome-session --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --autostart /usr/share/gdm/greeter/autostart
 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
 gdm-session-worker [pam/gdm-password]
 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run-script env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --session=ubuntu
 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu
 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
```

Comment: switching to lightdm solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Open Ubuntu Software Center, click search sign at the right upper corner of the window and type in the search field "Gnome extensions disable screen shield" phrase. You'll see the "Disable Screen Shield" Gnome shell extension.
[image]
Install the extension and voila - the curtain has disappeared.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on 18.04.01

Comment: Same here, running Ubuntu 19.04 & GNOME Shell 3.32.2
, it doesn't work even if Tweaks>Extensions>Disable screen shield is enabled, any hint anyone?

Comment: Sometimes works, sometimes not on Ubuntu 18.04...